# Implementation of switching images with fade to black?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, transition

There is following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Background: React.FC = () => {
    const images = [ "image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg" ];
    const [currentImage, setCurrentImage] = useState("")
    const [imageIndex, setImageIndex] = useState(0);

    const changeId = () => setImageIndex(id => id + 1);
    useEffect(() => {
         window.addEventListener("click", changeId);
         return () => window.removeEventListener("click", changeId);
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentImage(images[imageIndex]);
    }, [imageIndex])

    return (
        <img
           src={currentImage}
           alt={"background"}
        />
    );
};

export default Background;
```

I need to achieve smooth image switching. However, the image should first smoothly fade into black, and then a new image should appear from black. Therefore, using the transition property, I think this effect cannot be achieved.
p.s. If the click is pressed too often, interrupt the animation and change the picture abruptly.

- I tried to use css animation, but for some reason the image first "blinked" and then switched.
- I tried using the onTransitionEnd event, but sometimes it didn't work, and as a result, the new picture didn't appear, but only a black screen remained.

Comment: so what i need for achive this effect?